# Combine multiple arrays to one array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am developing chat api in codeigniter. Here is my controller and model.

```
//show message controller
public function to_user()
{
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$userto = $data->{'userto'};
$data=$this->um->to_user($userto);
echo json_encode($data);
}

//show message model
function to_user($userto)
{ 
  $this->db->select('message,from_user_email,reg_name,pic_url');
    $this->db->from('t_chat_msg');
    $this->db->where('to_user_email', $userto);
$this->db->join('registration','t_chat_msg.from_user_email=registration.email','inner');
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query; 
 }
```

When i hit in postman to get result using the parameter.

```
{
  "userto":"nomi_malik01@yahoo.com"
}

 Result:

 [
  {
    "message": "Hi.",
    "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
    "reg_name": "Tapy",
    "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png"
  },
  {
    "message": "Hello!Testing.",
    "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
    "reg_name": "Tapy",
    "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png"
  }
 ]
```

As you can notice email:nomi_malik01@yahoo.com has received couple of messages from email:tapy@live.com but they are shown in different arrays but i want to show them in single array like shown below. Please help me.

**Required Output:**

```
  {
    "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
    "reg_name": "Tapy",
    "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png",
    "message": [ 
      {
       "Hello!Testing.",
       "Hello!I am eating.",
       "Hello!Bye, I am going."
      } 
     ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_push for this. I think there is no function in CodeIgniter for this.

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp

Example for you:

```
$resp = array();
$first = true;

foreach($data as $d) {

    if($first === true) {
        $resp = array("from_user_email" => $d['from_user_email'],
                    "reg_name" => $d['reg_name'],
                    "pic_url" => $d['pic_url'],
                    "messages" => array());    
        $first = false;
    } else {
        array_push($resp['messages'], array("message" => $d['message']));
        //or
        array_push($resp['messages'], $d['message']);
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is join which i have used to fetch the picture of the sender. Where i shall apply array_push() function?

Comment: added an example for you. Just basic.